# Microsoft Word 2016 blacks out numbered lists

Tags: fonts

I have tried all the fixes listed for the blacked out numbering.  nothing sticks.  when I save and reopen its all back again.

[image: Blackouts]

I have also found that in trying to rectify what looks to be a font size problem I the multi-list set up function, I receive a funky error message.  there seems to be a character in the format to view (see highlight in screen shot) but it won't let me fix it.

[image: Font error]

Comment: Is the document a Word 2016 document, or is it from a previous version of Word?